# Need to upgrade the package done in Installshield professional edition 6.3 with installshield 2011

Tags: installshield

I have got a project for Installshield.

It has an application to which we need to package. But the challenge is currently they are using the 
Installshield professional edition 6.3, and all the process are run trough installscripts. 
Also they are using some scripts to upgrade the package every month whenever there is some upgrade. 
The files will copy from the server to the location and build.

To the same application, now we need to add some customization, which does not affect their previous
behaviour of the application. Every month they need to upgrade the package without actually repackaging
or upgrading through GUI and which should be done through scripts.

How do we actually handle this case. When we does not support Installshield professional edition 6.3 
anymore.

And that package needs to work in all operating systems from Windows 95.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this question has been up here for awhile, but I will answer it just in case it helps someone with the same issue.

InstallShield has pretty robust support for upgrading projects created in previous versions. 
Your best option is to purchase the latest version of InstallShield and upgrade the ISM (InstallShield Project File).  This process will create a backup of your previous Installer project.  The upgrade should import the project correctly as an InstallScript project (rather than an MSI flavor of project).

Once you finish upgrading your ISM project file from InstallShield 6.3 to the latest version, you should be able to edit the InstallScript rul files from within the InstallShield IDE just as you did previously with InstallShield 6.3

The InstallShield IDE has built-in options for supporting a wide variety of Windows operating systems.